# Compiling Java Applets

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I recently started making a Java applet game for the java4k game contest but I'm new with applets and I have some questions about them.

I have an applet written in eclipse and I can run it in eclipse using applet viewer but how do I compile it? There doesn't seem a option for compiling applets..

..and what is a jar archive?

Thanks.

Also here's my source in case you need it:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class game extends Applet implements KeyListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int x = 50,y = 50;
    public boolean right, left, down, up, lt = false, rt = true;
    public Image buffer;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    BufferedImage imgl = null;
    Graphics bg;

    public void init(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/player.png"));
        } catch (IOException e){}
        try {
            imgl = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/playerl.png"));
        } catch (IOException e){}
        addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(400,200);
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){
                if (right == true){x++;}
                if (left == true){x--;}
                if (up == true){y--;}
                if (down == true){y++;}
                repaint();
            }},10,10);
        buffer = createImage(400,200);
        bg = buffer.getGraphics();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        bg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //bg.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
        if (rt == true){
            bg.drawImage(img,x,y, this);
        }
        if (lt == true){
            bg.drawImage(imgl,x,y, this);
        }
        g.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = true;
            lt = true;
            rt = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = true;
            rt = true;
            lt = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = false;
        }
    }
    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: You really may want to clean up your question so we can help.  Perhaps some punctuation.

Comment: `class game extends Applet`  1) Please use common nomenclature, that should be `Game` 2) Come join us in this millennium and use `JApplet`. .. `ImageIO.read(new File("C:/player.png"));`  3) That won't work on the user machine since their file-system has no `player.png` on `C` drive (many will not have a `C` drive).  To load application resources, use an URL. `setSize(400,200);`  4) Will only work in testing, not while embedded. `Timer t = new Timer();` 5) If converting to Swing, use a `javax.swing.Timer`.  `public void update(Graphics g){` 6) Don't override that.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to export as a JAR file. To do this you will need to right-click the project > export.

Select Java > JAR file

In the JAR Export Dialog, select what parts you want to export (Export generated class files and resources) for your project. Probably want to specify the output folder as well. The rest of the options can be left as default and go to Finish.

You can run the JAR in a applet viewer or from a webpage in an APPLET tag, make sure to set the archive="jar file name".

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, right click the project, click export, and export as a jar.

Then you can embed this jar in your webpage to be run as an applet, or externally with appletviewer.

There's no difference between a JAR and an Archive Jar. JAR stands for "Java ARchive".

Answer (score 0):

You cant create self executive jar without main method.
Fortunately it's quite simple to do it.

You can create method called `public static void main(String[] args)` within your main class.
and then do something like this:

```
    yourmainclassname yourname = new yourmainclassname(); //create new object
    yourname.init(); //invoke the applet's init() method
    yourname.start(); //starts the applet
    // Create a window (JFrame) and make applet the content pane.
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Put something here"); 
    window.setSize(640, 480); //size in pixels
    window.setContentPane(theApplet); //
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

That's all. Next you can just export project to self executive JAR.